# How to deploy files to the test folder

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am writing a test project to test the e-mail functionality. This functionality opens an HTML file that contains the message template for the e-mail. When I try to run I get an error which reports that the template file could not be found. I have figured out that when running the test, the dll's etc. are copied to a different location which looks like:

```
C:\Users\Cornelis\AppData\Local\Temp\TestResults\Cornelis_CORNELISDESKTOP 2014-07-13 18_07_47\Out\
```

I searched around on the internet and find some partial solutions but none helped me completely to solve my problem. What I have found so far is:

- If I go to the properties of the file in my solution explorer, I set the value of the property 'Copy to output directory' to 'copy always'.
- I added the `DeploymentItemAttribute` to my test method. This caused my file to be copied into the debug folder of my unit test, but not to the folder mentioned earlier.
- I also found a lot of solution involving a `*.testsettings` where I had to turn on an option Enable Deployment. But if I add such a file to my solution, I get an error which says no tests could be found. And according to Microsoft I shouldn't use such settings file for what I want to reach:

> Caution
>
> Unit tests run more slowly if you use a test settings file. We
>   recommend that you do not use a test settings file with unit tests.
>   You can configure unit tests by using the .runsettings file instead.
>   To deploy additional files, use DeploymentItemAttribute.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx

What am I doing wrong here? What do I need to do so my test can find the template file I require?

Comment: Is the purpose of your test to validate that HTML template you have in source control is valid? If not, don't test it -- the templates files represent an external dependency that can (and should) be mocked at the time of testing to reduce coupling. Right now, you have a file system dependency, and your tests aren't actually unit tests at all. They're integration tests.

Comment: No, the template is required for the message/body of the e-mail I want to send. And I know it isn't according to the unit test best practice but I am actually trying to do integration tests here. But I guess the unit test built in functionality of VS isn't suitable for this (Hence the name Unit Test). I guess I have to find a different way to do my integration tests then. If you got any suggestions, they are very welcome.

Comment: What are you trying to test? The actual template should be irrelevant to your tests, unless you're testing the template itself. If you're testing the templating engine you wrote, you shouldn't need a physical file to test. Also, if you wrote your own templating engine, you probably didn't know that there already is one in the form of T4.